# What are the values for VLAN_NAME_TYPE when setting up a VLAN interface on Linux

Tags: rhel, bonding, vlan

When creating network interface files `ifcfg-tttN` (`ttt` in `{eth,em,bond}`) in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/` on RHEL/CentOS servers, what are the different values for `VLAN_NAME_TYPE` and what do they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter `VLAN_NAME_TYPE` defines the naming convention that you want to use for the VLAN device names, and thus for the file names.

Here are a few assumptions: 
- I'm using interface eth0. The configuration is the same for a bonding interface, where the physical device name would be `bond0`, or for the new Dell naming convention `emN`, `pSpN` [see RedHat manual](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/appe-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html).
- The VLAN id for the subnet `10.0.20.0/24` is `12`.

Here is the content of my `ifcfg-` file, to which I will append the VLAN parameters.

```
VLAN=yes
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=static
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=10.0.20.2
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
TYPE=Ethernet
MTU=1500
IPV6INIT=no

VLAN_NAME_TYPE=<see below>
DEVICE=<see below>
PHYSDEV=<optional, see below>
```

Possible values for VLAN_NAME_TYPE and their associated parameters are below.

The name of the file has to match the content of the `DEVICE` parameter with the prefix `ifcfg-`.

Note that if the parameter `DEVICE` doesn't contain the physical device, the parameter `PHYSDEV` is mandatory.

1. `VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID`

Name will look like:  `eth0.0012`

File name `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.0012`

```
DEVICE=eth0.0012
VLAN_NAME_TYPE=VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID
```

2. `VLAN_NAME_TYPE_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD`

Name will look like:  `vlan12`

File name `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-vlan12`

```
PHYSDEV=eth0
DEVICE=vlan12
VLAN_NAME_TYPE=VLAN_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
```

3. `VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD` (this is the default)

Name will look like:  `eth0.12`

File name `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0.12`

```
DEVICE=eth0.12
VLAN_NAME_TYPE=VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
```

4. `VLAN_NAME_TYPE_PLUS_VID`

Name will look like:  `vlan0012`

File name `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-vlan0012`

```
PHYSDEV=eth0
DEVICE=vlan0012
VLAN_NAME_TYPE=VLAN_NAME_TYPE_PLUS_VID
```

Source: [Source of the 8021q module for the linux kernel 2.6.32](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/8021q/vlan.c?v=2.6.32#L310)